# φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1) p and q are two big numbers find e such that gcd(e,φ(n)) = 1

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, cryptography

φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1)
p and q are two big numbers
find e such that gcd(e,φ(n)) = 1

consider p and q to be a very large prime number (Bigint). I want to find a efficient solution for this.

[Edit] I can solve this using a brute force method. But as the numbers are too big I need more efficient solution.
also   1< e < (p-1)(q-1)

Comment: Didn't RSA algorithm give you the explanation you are seeking?

Comment: A homework tag would seem appropriate

Comment: 1. Its not a homework 2. I am using RSA and want a effiecient soln for gcd

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you looking for and what are the given information? Because if what you look for is a value of e with p and q given, e=φ(n)+1 works...

Comment: @honeybadger: What have you tried until now? We are glad to help, but we won't make your homework.

Comment: @Gamecat @Grammin No offense but if anyone dont have answer please dont refer as homework. It seems to me that what we did in college has no relation with what we do at work. I mean should we stop going to college then?

Comment: Are you trying to implement RSA? Then, let me suggest to use an established crypto library. They are available for most languages. Implementing RSA from scratch is error-prone and, worse, may result in a working but insecure product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you choose `e` to be a prime number. A common choice is 65537. You then select `p` and `q` so that `gcd(p-1, e)=1` and `gcd(q-1, e)=1`, which just required you to check that `p-1` and `q-1` are not multiples of e (when you (rarely) find that one of them is, you generate a new prime instead).

65537 has the advantage of allowing you to optimize the public key operation by observing that `x^65537 = x^(2^16+1) = x^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2 * x (mod m)`, so you just need 16 modular squarings and a modular multiplication.

Comment: Now again the problem of finding p-1 and q-1 efficiently will arise. right?

Comment: Well, since e is a prime, it is easy. You just check that p-1 and q-1 are not multiples of e. If one of them are, you select another prime. It will happen 1/e times, so it will make your key-generation approximately (1+1/e) times slower.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide how big you want e to be. This is a system decision. Commonly, e used to be fixed at 3; more usual nowadays is e=65537. In these cases, e is prime, so (as others have already pointed out) you just have to check that (p-1)(q-1) is not a multiple of e.
But some system requirements specify a 32-bit random e. This is because some cryptographers feel that flaws are more likely to be discovered in fixed-exponent RSA systems than in random-exponent systems. (As far as I know, no concrete exploitation has been discovered for fixed-exponent systems; but cryptographers are paid to be over-cautious.)
So let's say you're stuck with having to generate a random 32-bit e that is co-prime to (p-1)(q-1). The simplest solution is this: Generate a random, odd 32-bit number e. Then calculate its inverse mod (p-1)(q-1). If this inverse calculation fails, because e is not co-prime to (p-1)(q-1), then try again.
This is a reasonable, practical solution. You will need to calculate the inverse anyway, and computing an inverse doesn't take much longer than computing a gcd.
If you really need to make it as fast as you can, you can look for small prime factors of (p-1)(q-1) and trial-divide e by these factors: if you find small prime factors, then you can speed up your search for e; if you don't, then the search will probably terminate quickly.
Another reasonable soltuion is to generate a random 32-bit prime e, and check (p-1)(q-1) for divisibility by e. Whether this is allowed would depend on your system requirements. Are you setting these system requirements yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Pick first prime number >= 3  that satisfies this.
If you are looking for speed, you might use small exponent.

There might be two problems whit 2 exponents.

- You should not use small exponents to encrypt same massage whit multiple schemes. (for instance if there are tree private/public pairs whit exp = 3 you can use Gauss’s algorithm to recover plaintext.
- You should not send short messages because attacker might use only cube root to recover this.

Considering these weaknesses you might use this scheme. And as far as I know number 3 is common number for e.

By the way, brute forcing few numbers is negligible compared to checking for primality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misstated the problem; `e=1` works nicely for the one you've written.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do then is compute de = 1 mod phi(n). This is actually very quick - you simply need to use the extended Euclidean Algorithm on e and phi n. Doing so will allow you to compute de + k\phi(n) = 1 which is to say you have computed the inverse of e under \phi(n).

Edit, [Rasmus Faber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5542/rasmus-faber) is correct, you do need to verify that gcd(e, \phi(n)) = 1. The extended Euclidean Algorithm will still do this for you - you compute both the gcd and the multiples of e, phi(n). This tells you what d is, namely that d is the inverse of e, modulu phi n which tells you that t^ed = t^1 modulo phi n.

As for doing this in practice, well, I strongly suggest [using a bignum library](http://www.mpir.org/); rolling your own arbitrary precision euclidean extended algorithm isn't easy. Here is [one such function](http://gmplib.org/manual/Extended-GCD.html) that will do this efficiently for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: He is performing key generation. The usual formulations of RSA key generation just specifies that gcd(e,phi(pq))=1, not how to ensure this. Choosing a random e risks that gcd(e,phi(pq))!=1, so you have to to /something/ to prevent this.

Comment: Read up on the Maths. If you choose e to be some known prime, then p and q to be two other primes, and n=pq, then n cannot have a factor of e. That is the strength and whole point of RSA. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic says any number n must have a unique factorisation of primes, so if n has p and q as its prime factors, it cannot have e. Hence the gcd must be one. So choose e, then generate p and q but reject p and q if they are e. Easy.

Comment: If e, p and q are primes, then gcd(e, phi(pq)) is not guaranteed to be 1. Quick counter-example: e=3, p=5, q=7. phi(pq)=24, gcd(e,phi(pq))=3.

Comment: Ah, true, I am wrong, good point, I'm being hasty.